# why does the loop on this program time out?

Tags: java, string, loops, indexof

it works fine for some strings, but for some reason it does not work for the last three. I see no difference to the type of strings being entered and I expect indx to evaluate to -1, but for some reason it does not on the last three strings. I don't understand why.
edit: problem solved. As you guys said, I was taking the substring of str instead of news within the loop. Sorry for such a simple mistake guys, I'm just starting to code and these are the details I need to pay attention to more. Also as I am working within the codingbat website there is no debugger, but I also want to highly recommend that website for other beginners. It will give you many example problems to begin coding on. Thanks again.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKmUX.png)
code:

```
public String stringYak(String str) {
  int indx = str.indexOf("yak");
  String news =str;
    for(;indx!=-1;)
    {
      news = (str.substring(0,indx) + str.substring(indx+3,str.length()));
      indx = news.indexOf("yak");

    }
    return news;

}
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: Please add all the relevant code here, rather than linking to images. SO users should be answer your question without having to visit external sites.

Comment: You are substring'ing the original `str` value, not the modified `news` value, so if there is more than one `yak`, it'll run forever. Which would have easily been noticeable if you had **debugged** your code, so: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 1):

Because loop never breaks.

You are taking substring from `str` index from `news` inside the loop.

May be you want to take both substring and index from `news`.